# how to reading .txt file , and adding space after specific position/index , for each line in python

Tags: python

I want to read all line in txt.file, and add space at after specific position/index.

suppose my file contains:

```
 1234567891011 12134516 17
```

in the above file: I want to add space after index/position [8],[10],[16],and [20], means after irrerular position/index.

expected output :

```
 123456789 10 11 121 3451 6 17
```

As a reminder: I don't want to replace elements, just add space after a specific position/index

note: all line in the file as the same structure.

reading and writing .txt file and add space after at specific positon/index.

my file contain :

```
 1234567891011 12134516 17 

 6546546546456 35654554 54
```

expected output :

```
 123456789 10 11 121 3451 6 17 

 654654654 64 56 356 5455 4 54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file line by line and putting the output in an array using the following codes:

```
  f=open('configuration.txt','r+') 

  lines=f.readlines()
```

Now you can have access to each line as a string. exp: line 0 by "lines[0]" and you can put space in the 8th index like this:

```
lines[0]=lines[0][:8] + ' ' + lines[0][8:]
```

In order to rewrite the file use "".join(lines) to convert a list to string

```
 f.write("".join(lines))
```

---

As I understand the following code will solve your problem:

```
f=open('test.txt','r+')
lines=f.readlines()

for i in range(0,len(lines)):
  if lines[i]=='\n':
     continue
  lines[i]=lines[i][:9] + ' ' + lines[i][9:]
  lines[i]=lines[i][:12] + ' ' + lines[i][12:]
  lines[i]=lines[i][:19] + ' ' + lines[i][19:]
  lines[i]=lines[i][:24] + ' ' + lines[i][24:]

f.seek(0,0)
f.write("".join(lines))
```

Comment: @pahlevan, please, I want to add a space after the [8] and after the [10], and so on ....
Not a space among them.

Comment: I edited my answer and I tested with your example and it works fine. really hope it will help you.